# What does a MultiPass do?

Tags: the-fifth-element

One of the most-remembered catch phrases of *The Fifth Element* is when Leeloo, at the spaceport about to board the starship to Phloston Paradise, exclaims,

> Leeloo Dallas MultiPass!

At this point, she holds up what looks like a smart card of some sort.

What exactly does a MultiPass *do* for its holder?

- Is it a passport or some other type of identification card used for passing government checkpoints?
- Is it a payment card?
- Does it hold passenger booking data?

Comment: just going by the events at the shuttleport we can probably assume it doesn't hold booking Data as Korben was sent tickets (remember he was arguing with his mother about the contest before they arrived) and that it wasn't used for payment here because the tickets were for free (though i don't recall seeing the MultiPass outside here), but we know it's for iding as when David goes to check in he's denied because Korben had already checked in Leeloo

Comment: @Memor-X yes, I figured it was probably a passport, but it's also plausible that the physical tickets were scanned into the MultiPass in some way or that additional services were purchased using it.

Comment: @Memor-X "ID" is capitalized. This is especially important if you're going add stuff like "ing" to it.

Comment: Same thing a SoloPass does, but more.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Based on the front of the pass (notably the payment card symbols, the AT&T symbol and driver's licence type notification), it appears to be a combined passport/driving licence/phone card/payment card.

[image]

This is backed up by the [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1458174.The_Fifth_Element) which calls it a passport.

> ***Korben grabbed the passport*** and read it. “Uh, yes,” he said.
>   “Newlyweds. Love at first sight. You meet, something goes ‘tilt,’ you
>   get married, you hardly know each other. Right, darling?”

As does the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Fifth-Element,-The.html)

> **CORNELIUS:** *Did you get them?*
>
> David hands Cornelius two passports.
>
> **CORNELIUS:** *Excellent... Leeloo Dallas.*
>
> He hands it to her.  The name makes her smile.
>
> **CORNELIUS:** *And Korben David Dallas.*

Luc Besson just says (in an [AMA interview](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/2ety7z/luc_besson_here_ama/ck31iin/?context=1)) that it's **bigger and better than a credit card**

> **Q.** *First off, let me say, The Fifth Element is by far my favorite movie of all time. My question is, what all services come with the
>   multipass?*
>
> **A.** *Oh god... i dont remember! But it's bigger and better than a Platinum credit card!*

Comment: Not just any credit card, but a Platinum Card.

Comment: OMG... all this time I thought it was Corbin Dallas.